# How can I turn a multi-line string into an array where each element is a line of said string?

Tags: c#

Lets say I have

```
string str = @"Line 1
Line 2
Line 3";
```

How can I turn this into an array where the 3 elements are "Line 1", "Line 2" and "Line 3".

Comment: Maybe `String.Split` can help you?

Comment: Parse the string, look for line breaks and put them in array.

Comment: you can simply traverse this string and create a word till you face any '\n' char. By this you can have a word array.

Comment: `var lines = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox { Text = str }.Lines;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this , The RemoveEmptyEntries option will remove empty lines from the text.

```
string[] splitted = str.Split(new string[] {System.Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var strArray = str.Split(new [] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: That's going to result in blank strings between the `\r` and `\n` characters.

Comment: @juharr. Fair enough. Edited to remove empty items.

Comment: Note that you now only split on the `\r\n` combination where as before you were splitting if there was only a single `\r` or a single `\n`.  This would now remove blank lines which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Based on his requirement (that the desired output based on the sample input is three lines), this should suffice. Maybe you should propose an alternate solution...?

Comment: No need since this is a clear duplicate.