# How to split a message so I can assign it to different variables?

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm having trouble trying to split a message I receive. I am splitting it because I need to assign the name part to a name variable and the information part to the information variable. The message I receive is:

> PUT /Person\r\n\r\nis in this building\r\n

"Person" is the name and "is in this building" is the location. this is also a 0.9 protocol.

For another message I managed to do it, this was the code I did:

```
string tmp1 = null;
temp = line.Remove(0, 6); //removes first part to bring name to beginning
line = temp.Replace(" HTTP/1.0\\r\\nContent-Length", ""); //removes quote from message
string[] tmp = temp.Split(':'); //Splits name and location apart
name = tmp[0];
tmp1 = tmp[1];                  //Name and location set
location = tmp1.Remove(0, 11);  //further trimming to location
tmp1 = location;          
amount = tmp1.Count();
location = tmp1.Remove(amount - 4);  //Location set
```

Above is an example of something that I have done, it receives a message similar to the quote I provided and basically splits it apart somewhere and gets rid of the things like "\r\n" or protocol information that I don't want. However, It is also at risk if a message comes in with information including ":" as it would always split. so I am at a fault there.

I am unsure what I could do to extract the information I want as the incoming data in the message could be of any length. So it's fairly difficult. I also thought of splitting it into arguments by "" but it does not let me since it's part of things like "\r\n" etc.

What could I do?
Hope what I provided is useful.

Closest thing I have got to splitting it properly is doing

```
liness = line.Split('\\');
```

but it splits it into more than 2 or 3 arguments because I am not removing the "r" and "n" from "\r\n" either.

Comment: Split it into lines, parse the lines properly for the information you want. It’s much easier than replacing parts of strings etc. And you don’t have to assume the data is always exactly the same.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: the string actually contains the characters "\r\n" ?

Comment: Yes, It contains "\r\n".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if the string really contains the actual characters "\r\n" etc first thing I would do is fix that because that's plain nasty. Then use this q&a to split it up

[How can I turn a multi-line string into an array where each element is a line of said string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758587/how-can-i-turn-a-multi-line-string-into-an-array-where-each-element-is-a-line-of)

```
    var str = "PUT /Person\\r\\n\\r\\nis in this building\\r\\n";
    var clean = str.Replace("\\r\\n", System.Environment.NewLine);
    string[] splitted = clean.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string line in splitted) {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

Comment: It does it. and Yes, it is nasty. What is happening is, a message is sent from a server with an argument in between "". so it gets sent to me like so as "POST /PERSON \r\rn\r\n is in building" and I am reading this message by:
 string message = null;
 message += sr.readLine();   //Incoming message being analysed.

If that helps